# create dynamic pdfs in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am required to create a pdf document in wordpress while using data within the database, such as name, address, and other fields.  This is not a direct form-to-pdf solution.  I am trying to create a widget that has an independent pdf.  In python I would use a pdf generation script.  How do I do this in wordpress?

Comment: Try [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php).

Comment: I like the library....seems to work great.  But how do I build then?  Do I create a plugin? or is there a PHP-based custom plugin that I can employ?

Comment: I don't know of anyone whose built a Wordpress implementation of mPDF, so you'll probably need to create your own plugin.